# Conditionally building firestore query with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a firestore query conditionally but I'm getting a typescript error and I don't know what I'm missing. Below is my code.

```
const getInitialData = ({ collection, orderClause }: ICollection) => {
   let query = app.collection(collection);

   if (orderClause) {
     query = query.orderBy(orderClause.value, orderClause.direction);
   }

   query.get().then((response) => {
     const genericData: T[] = [];
     response.forEach((doc) => {
       genericData.push(dataResolver(doc));
     });

     setData(genericData);
   });
};
```

I'm getting the error "Type 'Query' is missing the following properties from type 'CollectionReference': id, parent, path, doc, addts(2739)" when updating the query inside the if statement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Give `query` a wider type of `CollectionReference | Query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.collection` returns a CollectionReference object. `query.orderBy` returns a Query object.  You can't assign a Query object to a CollectionReference.  However, Query is a subclass of CollectionReference as you can see in the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference).  What you can do here is make sure that your query variable is typed as a Query instead of the inferred CollectionReference so that it can hold references for either type without casting.

```
let query: Query = app.collection(collection);
```